# Accessing the value of a field inside a class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I apologize in advance for my clumsy English. I've been writing in React for a while now, but this is my first encounter with this issue. You can see the service class, which includes the #basketUrl (just string "/basket") field with a request link and two implementations of the same method, createBasket.

```
import $axios from "../axios";
import { ServerPaths } from "../enum/ServerPaths";

class BasketService {
  #basketUrl = ServerPaths.BASKETS;
  #basketProductUrl = ServerPaths.BASKET_PRODUCTS;

  async createBasket (userId) {
    await $axios.post(`${this.#basketUrl}`, { userId });
  }

  createBasket = async (userId) => {
    await $axios.post(`${this.#basketUrl}`, { userId });
  }
}
```

In the first case, the code doesn't recognize 'this'; it interprets it as undefined, hence 'this.url - cannot read properties of undefined,' as there's no variable 'url'. In the second case - all ok.

At the same time, in the online compiler, the same code ran smoothly and provided me with the value of the field.

Please explain Why only the arrow function works in my React code.

Everything works with an arrow function, but I want to get to the bottom of this question.

Comment: please post actual code, not images. Read [Why should I not upload images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: This is my first question, I didn't know that. Thank you, I've modified the question.

Comment: I doubt when writing the prototypal method like in the first case ... `class BasketService { #basketUrl = 'https://foo.bar'; #basketProductUrl = 'https://foo.bar/baz'; async createBasket (userId) { return await fetch(\`${this.#basketUrl}\`, { userId }); } }` ... and creating an instance from `BasketService` and invoking `createBasket` on this instance that the method's `this` context does not match the instance. Running it through a debugger proves this claim too. Everything works as expected ... `this.#basketUrl` ... can be always accessed and resolved.

Comment: @PeterSeliger "*invoking `createBasket` on this instance*" - well that'll be the issue

Comment: @dyakonovr Please see the duplicate targets for how the `this` keyword works and what was most likely the issue. If you need further assistance or explanations, please [edit] your question to also include the part of the code that calls the `createBasket` method. Most likely this was a different kind of call between the "online compiler" and your "React code".